# Transform upper right triangular matrix given the columns in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a vector containing something like

```
{1,  2, 1,  4, 5, 1,  7, 8 ,9, 1 }
```

So the vector represent the columns of an upper right matrix

```
  1 2 4 7
  0 1 5 8
  0 0 1 9
  0 0 0 1
```

How could I use the vector and get from

```
{1,  2, 1,  4, 5, 1,  7, 8 ,9, 1 }
```

to

```
  1 2 4 7
  2 1 5 8
  4 5 1 9
  7 8 9 1
```

as a vector

```
{ 1,2,4,7,
  2,1,5,8, 
  4,5,1,9,
  7,8,9,1 }
```

In fact After reviewing the code, the solution is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        v[cols * i + j] = v[cols * j + i] = w[k++];
```

Comment: do you want just to copy the entries to another container, or random access?

Comment: well, to get a vector representing the complete matrix like:
`{ 1,2,4,7,
   2,1,5,8,
   4,5,1,9,
   7,8,9,1 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int k=0;
for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j<=i; ++j)
        v[i][j]=v[j][i]=w[k++];
```

Assuming source vector is w, dest is v.

If it should be 1D, not 2D, then `[i][j]` should be changed to `[4*i+j]`.

**EDIT**
This can be done 'in-place', but it is a little tricky. In order not to overwrite values you haven't used yet, you have to loop backwards and to make two passes:

```
int k=10;
for(int i = 3; i >=0; --i)
    for(int j = i; j >= 0; --j)
        v[4*i+j]=v[--k];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        v[4*j+i]=v[4*i+j];
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that without using 2  vectors, I mean using only source vector, guess not right?

Comment: @cMinor It is, but you'd have to resize the source vector.

Comment: The second solution works great, but the first one, I am getting differen result, I changed as you suggested `for (int i = 1; i < cols; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
                v[4 * i + j] = v[4 * j + i] = w[k++];`  and getting `0 1 1 1 1 2 4 7 1 4 5 8 1 7 8 9` instead `1,2,4,7, 2,1,5,8, 4,5,1,9, 7,8,9,1` what did I do wrong?